If $F:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$ is continuous with $|F(x)-F(y)|\geq \lambda|x-y|$, then $F$ is surjective.
I know that this question has been asked for several times (such as this post and the one-dimensional case). However, I still couldn't find an answer without using invariance of domain. The original question is stated as:
If $F:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$ is continuous with $|F(x)-F(y)|\geq \lambda |x-y|$ for some $\lambda>0$, then $F$ is a homeomorphism.
Here is my attempt:
It is clear that $F$ is injective and $F^{-1}:F(\mathbb R^m)\to \mathbb R^m$ is continuous. Hence,  it remains to show that $F$ is surjective. As $\mathbb R^m$ is connected, we can infer that $F(\mathbb R^m)=\mathbb R^m$ by proving that $F(\mathbb R^m)$ is a clopen subset. The closedness of $F(\mathbb R^m)$ is easy: Suppose $q_n$ is a sequence in $F(R^m)$ with $q_n\to q$. Then there exists $p_n\in \mathbb R^m$ such that $F(p_n)=q_n$. Since $|q_n-q_m|\geq \lambda |p_n-p_m|$ and $\{q_n\}$ is Cauchy, $p_n$ is Cauchy, which implies that $p_n\to p$ for some $p\in \mathbb R^m$. Them by the continuity of $F$, $q=F(p)\in F(\mathbb R^m)$.
However, I still need show that $F(\mathbb R^m)$ is open and that is where I get stumped. Since it  is a question given in our introductory real analysis courses, invariance of domain is completely out of scope of this curriculum. Thus, I seek for an elementary solution.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075972/42969

@MartinR This deals with a continuously differentiable $f$.

@MartinR I know that if $F$ is $C^1$, then we can use inverse function theorem. However, $F$ is only assumed to be continuous.

@stange Sadly, it does not solve my question. It still relies on using invariance of domain to prove $F(\mathbb R^m)$ is open, which is the approach I wish to avoid.

A particular case of your statement is obtained when the function has the form $F(x)=x+\phi(x)$, where $\phi:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ is a contraction. In this case, the standard elementary approach (at least the one I know) shows that $F(\mathbb R^m)=\mathbb R^m$ by using the contraction mapping theorem. Could the general case be reduced to this one? I don't know, it's just an idea. Possibly, for general $F$ the said theorem has to be replaced by some stronger result (this would explain the absence of elementary proofs).

(1.) the criterion implies $\Vert x \Vert \to \infty \implies \Vert F(x)\Vert \to \infty$ so we could extend to the sphere $S^m$ (which also implies $F$ is a closed map). If $F$ were not surjective then it would imply a continuous injection from $S^m$ into $\mathbb R^m$, violating Borsuk-Ulam, though this is close to invariance of domain.  (2.) this question was asked (and deleted) a couple weeks ago and is a problem from chapter 4 of Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis which notably does not have multivariable Inverse Function Theorem till chapter 5.

This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111299/if-f-mathbbrm-rightarrow-mathbbrm-is-continuous-and-fx-f is $\mathrm{NOT}$ the answer to this question. It was asked to prove it $\mathrm{WITHOUT}$ invariance of domain. Further, the OP knows this post (see first sentence). So, why was this question closed?

Maybe there is a chance to use Baire's category theorem in some way to show that the image is dense?

"Since it is a question given in our introductory real analysis courses" - in that case you should get a solution and should present it here.

@PaulFrost I am going to ask my lecturer/TA about this. Hope I can get an elementary solution, which would be quite surprising as the answer below mentioned a strong counterexample, tho.

@SuperSupao Did you ask your lecturer/TA about this?

Here is my take. If you were to prove surjectivity, you will need to use (or to prove) some nontrivial facts about topology of $\mathbb R^n$ which are not covered in a typical undergraduate real analysis/general topology class, such as the invariance of domain theorem. Here is an example of a metric space $(X,d)$ which is path-connected, locally compact, complete and a continuous expanding map $F: X\to X$. (Moreover, it satisfies the Heine-Borel property: a subset of $X$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.) The image of the map $F$ will be closed but not open.
Consider the following version of Hawaiian Earrings:
For $n\ge 3$ take $X$ to be the union of round spheres $S(k {\mathbf e}_1, k)\subset \mathbb R^n, k\in \mathbb N$, ($\mathbb R^n$ is equipped with the standard metric), centered at $k {\mathbb e}_1$ and of the radius $k$, together with the coordinate hyperplane orthogonal to the vector $\mathbf e_1$. Use the restriction of the standard metric on $\mathbb R^n$ to get a metric $d$ on $X$. The resulting metric space $(X,d)$ is complete, path-connected, locally compact, hence, shares all the basic properties with $\mathbb R^n$. However, it is not a topological manifold.
Take the map $F(\mathbf x)=2\mathbf x$; $F: X\to X$ is continuous and satisfies the inequality:
$$
d(F(\mathbf x), F(\mathbf y))=2 d(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) 
$$
for all pairs of points in $X$. But this map is not surjective.
Why is $X$ not a manifold? Because it has a "cut-point", a point $p$ such that $X\setminus \{p\}$ is disconnected. (This point is the origin.) By multiplying this example by the real line you get a similar example which has no cut-points. It is still not a manifold but it has a "cut-line." Why a connected topological manifold of dimension $\ge 3$ cannot have a cut-line (i.e. a subset $A$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ such that removing $A$ disconnects the manifold)? I do not know of any easy proof of this result which avoids some algebraic topology or algebraic topology in disguise. (In contrast, it is elementary to see that a connected manifold of dimension $\ge 2$ cannot have cut-points.)
By further modifying the above example, one gets a similar example where the metric $d$ is uniquely geodesic: Every two points are connected by a length-minimizing path, such a path is unique (up to a reparameterization) and depends continuously on the end-points. (This is another property one has in $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard metric.)
Lastly, I think it is irresponsible to give this  problem in introductory analysis courses without discussing first the invariance of domain theorem or assuming $C^1$-smoothness of $F$.

The space $X$ is not complete. One must add the hyperplane orthogonal to $e_1$ to $X$.

@psl2Z: Right....

Couldn't we also take $X= {x_1 \geq 1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (a translated half-space, with standard metric) and $F: X \to X, x \mapsto 2x$? This would even be a topological manifold with boundary, contractible, uniquely geodesic, complete and locally compact. But $F$ is not surjective.

@psl2Z: Right, good point.
